# Выделение запятыми оборота

Tags: пунктуация

Уважаемые господа, правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении:
"Для этой высшей цели компания с первого дня постоянно наращивая усилия, ведет техническое перевооружение транспортной базы...".
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна или после "компания", или после "дня" - в зависимости от того, что происходит с первого дня: наращивание усилий или техническое перевооружение (смотря что хочет подчеркнуть автор). Мне больше нравится так:

*Для этой высшей цели компания с первого дня, постоянно наращивая усилия, ведет техническое перевооружение транспортной базы...*

Если два наречия "с первого дня" и "постоянно" находятся в составе одного оборота, то возникает желание одно из них убрать.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, "с первого дня постоянно наращивая усилия" надо взять в запятые. То есть, пропущена запятая после "компания"